# Bundle of array of arraylist

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

How can I put an array of arrayList into a Bundle?

```
ArrayList < myObjects >[] mElements;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `YourObject` implement the [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface, then use [`bundle.putParcelableArraylist(theParcelableArraylist)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29).

Edit: whoops misread the question. Why do you want to save an array of arraylist? If its for persisting in an orientation change, maybe you want to use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` instead?

Edit 2: Ok, here goes. Create a new `Wrapper` class that implements `Parcelable` (note that `myObjects` also have to be parcelable). The `writeToParcel` method will look something like this:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
  dest.writeInt(mElements.length);
  for(ArrayList<MyObject> element : mElements) {
    dest.writeParcelableArray(element.toArray(new MyObject[0]), flags);
  }
}
```

And the constructor:

```
private Wrapper(Parcel in) {
  int length = in.readInt();
  //Declare list
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    MyObject[] read = in.readParcelableArray(Wrapper.class.getClassLoader());
    //add to list
  }
}
```

Comment: It is mostly for orientation changes but I need it as well to accommodate the activity lifecycle.

Comment: I think you can create a wrapper class that implements parcelable and do it in a not so elegant way. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible using bundle, as bundle allows arraylist of primitives only...

Try to use parcleable or application level data or static variable (bad practice).

Answer (score 0):

If your objects support serialization, marked with the `Serializable` interface, then you should be able to use `bundle.putSerializable`.

`ArrayList` supports `Serializable` , but I'm not sure about a plain `array`.

Answer (score 0):

I just use `putSerializable(myarraylistofstuff)` and then I get back with a cast using `get()`, you just need to silence the unchecked warning. I suspect (correct me if wrong) you can pass any object faking it as `Serializable`, as long you stay in the same process it will pass the object reference. This approach obviously does not work when passing data to another application.

**EDIT:** Currently android passes the reference only between fragment, I've tried to pass an arbitrary object to an `Activity`, it worked but the object was different, same test using arguments of `Fragment` showed same `Object` instead.

Anyway it deserializes and serializes fine my `Object`, if you have a lot of objects it's better to use `Parcel` instead